# How to display messages on the asp textbox while waiting on a long WCF service call

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, wcf, webforms

I have two WCF service calls:

```
[OperationContract]
void ClosePeriod();
[OperationContract]
string GetLogs();
```

ClosePeriod method runs a stored procedure that takes 1 hour, and it generates log messages.
GetLogs method returns the log messages generated from ClosePeriod method.

I'm trying to display the log messages on the ASP.Net webpage while waiting on the ClosePeriod service call.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelClosing" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Timer ID ="TimerLog" runat ="server" Interval ="3000" OnTick="TimerLog_Tick" Enabled="true"></asp:Timer>
        <table>         
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 70px">
                        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="BtnExecuteClosing" Text="Execute" Width="105px" Height="35px"  OnClick="BtnExecuteClosing_Click" />
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p>Process Log:</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtProcessLog" runat="server" Width="930px" Height="270" TextMode="MultiLine" Style="resize: none;"
                        ReadOnly="true" Text=""> 
                    </asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

so far I tried to call ClosePeriod method asynchronously, and I tried to update TxtProcessLog textbox using the timer.

```
protected async void BtnExecuteClosing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)        
{
    await webservice.ClosePeriodAsync();
}

protected void TimerLog_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string log = webservice.GetLogs();
    TxtProcessLog.Text = log ; 

}
```

But the TxtProcessLog textbox is updated after the ClosePeriod service call is completed. 
Am I doing something wrong? Please suggest any other approaches.

Answer (score 1):

What does ClosePeriod do? Writing many Logs to a DB table?
Then your code should work fine.
If "webservice.GetLogs()" returns string.empty then nothing will be displayed.
The ClosePeriod call from your UpdatePanel should be async, otherwise the all subsequent calls will be blocked.

Comment: For testing purpose, I added System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000); in ClosePeriod. GetLogs() does not return an empty string.

Comment: Avoid using timers in updatepanel:
http://encosia.com/aspnet-ajax-timer-trouble-location-is-key/

A workaround would be to write a clientside script that triggers a button inside the updatepanel in a certain interval (setTimeout(func,3000);), that calls the getlogs method on the serverside. make the button not visible via css-> display:none.

It's not a nice way but should work.
Ideally you would call a WCF service method or page method "getlogs" and do the calls via jQuery.